# facebook developer toolkit > determine if a user likes a fan page in an application

Tags: facebook, toolkit

How can i check if a user is a fan of a page in my application using facebook developer toolkit? (without getting the user_likes permission, i saw an application doing this, which only gets the default permission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FQL:

```
select uid from page_fan where page_id=<page_id> and uid=<user_id>
```

see [`page_fan`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan) table

Comment: i get an error <error_code>104</error_code>
<error_msg>Requires valid signature</error_msg>